# IOS Tab Bar properties

Tags: ios, tabbar

I changed my tab bar items. I added custom button. But I can't see my button clearly. How can I fix it?

Button text is "chat". But it isn't fully displayed.

[image]

Comment: what are the dimensions of the images you added?

Comment: Show the code you're using too

Comment: Ios tab bar buttons use only the alpha channel of a png which is then tinted with the tabbar's tint when selected. How does your PNG look with only the alpha channel?

Comment: @RobP 23x46 images size.

Comment: @DovD. If I change my image format will it be fix ?

Comment: @Wain I added from navigation controller->tab bar item-> image image format "PNG". I didn't use code for it.

Comment: It's the size, and the icon should not have the text in it, just the glyph.

Comment: @DovD. Should I just use icon without text ?

Comment: You can set the text separately with setTitle: i think.